# How to select a record with more information?

Tags: sql-server

[image]

```
id  first       middle  last
1   Mike                Tyson
2   Nikki       Roy     James
2   Nikki               James
3   Rob     
3   Rob         Van 
3   Rob         Van      Dam
```

Desired output for select statement

```
id  first   middle  last
1   Mike            Tyson
2   Nikki   Roy     James
3   Rob     Van      Dam
```

How I can write the query

Comment: Do your own work and then come here for help. Don't ask someone to write your code for you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Explain your logic. What happens if you have another entry with `3   Rob         Van      Dam`? And why isn't id unique?

Comment: Have you even attempted anything????

Comment: As for "how": with a `SELECT` statement. It'll contain a `FROM`, as well as an `ORDER BY` and `TOP` (probably with a `WITH TIES`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will first want to ORDER BY such that all rows that have no have a middle name at located at the bottom of each `id`. So for example `ORDER BY first ORDER BY middle` then perform `SELECT DISTINCT(*) FROM <table_name> WHERE (first IS NOT NULL) AND (last IS NOT NULL)`. This will grab the last entry of each `id` with the middle name if it has one otherwise it will just grab it without a middle name. This assumes that each person has a first and last name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to elaborate on Ely's answer:

> You will first want to ORDER BY such that all rows that have no have a
>   middle name at located at the bottom of each id. So for example ORDER
>   BY first ORDER BY middle then perform SELECT DISTINCT(*) FROM
>    WHERE (first IS NOT NULL) AND (last IS NOT NULL). This
>   will grab the last entry of each id with the middle name if it has one
>   otherwise it will just grab it without a middle name. This assumes
>   that each person has a first and last name.

I noticed your question has been down-voted, but it *is* a legitimate question and one that is not as simple as it may look--not to mention the many different ways of addressing your need. My take is to use a CROSS JOIN on the data in question.

Here's is a simple example that will hopefully send you in the right direction. You can run this in SSMS.

First, I created a table variable and inserted your sample data, like so:

```
DECLARE @names TABLE ( [id] INT, [first] VARCHAR(50), [middle] VARCHAR(50), [last] VARCHAR(50) );

INSERT INTO @names (
    [id], [first], [middle], [last]
)
VALUES
  ( 1, 'Mike', '', 'Tyson' )
, ( 2, 'Nikki', 'Roy', 'James' )
, ( 2, 'Nikki', '', 'James' )
, ( 3, 'Rob', '', '' )
, ( 3, 'Rob', 'Van', '' )
, ( 3, 'Rob', 'Van', 'Dam' );
```

Then I wrote a SELECT with a CROSS JOIN that returns a single row for each id that has most complete data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [n].[id]
    , [fullNames].[first]
    , [fullNames].[middle]
    , [fullNames].[last]
FROM @names n
CROSS APPLY (

    SELECT TOP 1 
        [@names].[first], [@names].[middle], [@names].[last] 
    FROM @names 
    WHERE 
        [@names].[id] = [n].[id]
    ORDER BY
        [@names].[first] DESC, [@names].[middle] DESC, [@names].[last] DESC

) AS [fullNames]
ORDER BY
    [id];
```

Which returns the following:

```
+-------------------------------+
|  id  | first | middle | last  |
| ----+-------+--------+------- |
| 1   | Mike  |        | Tyson  |
| 2   | Nikki | Roy    | James  |
| 3   | Rob   | Van    | Dam    |
+-------------------------------+
```

Notes:

The initial **SELECT DISTINCT** ensures that only a single, unique "id" value  is returned for each row contained in the *@names* resultset.

The **TOP 1** used in the CROSS JOIN grabs a single record for the id in question, while the **ORDER BY DESC** on *each* column ensures that the record with the most complete data for that id ( `WHERE [@names].[id] = [n].[id]` ) is on top.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for solving the issue. It was a vital part of solving the sql I was working on. I appreciate you help.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark it as the answer if in fact that what this is. :)